# Spring and Gradle build: No such property: mainClassName for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot 1.1 and 1.3 project and occasionally during changes of `build.gradle` I got error

> No such property: mainClassName for class:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file ... line: 43
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project '...'.
>
>   > No such property: mainClassName for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE' //1.1.7.RELEASE'
        ...
    }
}

// Application Plugins
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

Line 43 is `mainClassName = 'com....Main'`

Comment: What is line 43 ? We need more contextual information

Comment: Line 43 is mainClassName = 'com....Main'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can only can tell, that for Spring Boot 1.1 gradle plugin

`mainClassName =` works without `apply plugin: 'application'`

But for Spring Boot 1.3 that would be error.
So Spring Boot 1.1 gradle plugin is applying application_plugin.

I can see that comparing `gradle tasks` output, that has tasks defined by application_plugin
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks

Answer (score 0):

This was proposed by @ToYonos

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging :

> The main class that you want to launch can either be specified using a configuration option, or by adding a Main-Class attribute to the manifest. If you don’t specify a main class the plugin will search for a class with apublic static void main(String[] args)method.

So either you remove the `mainClassName` directive or you set it like this :

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'demo.Application' 
}
```